# I have question about one2many and many2one field in odoo 10

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-10

If the user has already selected a value (list generated from Many2one) in a record, Now I don't want to show that value in the list that is generated from Many2one fields for any new value (records), this edit can performed in .xml file

Answer (score 0):

Setup another `One2many` field `field_ids` on the comodel that is the model in related in the Many2one relationship. Add an `Integer` field `relation_count` with computed function `_get_size`, that computed function depends on the One2many field `field_ids` and returns the size of that field. Now on the view, set domain to the `Many2one` field such that `[('relation_count', '=', 0)]`, which will only limit to list records that is not yet selected, thus relation count being `0`.